# ASP.NET Core - change JWT SecurityKey during runtime

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt

Having a configuration similar to this:

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddJwtBearer(x =>
{ 
   x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
   {
      ValidateIssuer = false,
      ValidateAudience = false,

      ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
      IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Convert.FromBase64String(config.JwtSecret)),

      ValidateLifetime = true,
      ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
    };
 });
```

**Is there a proper way of changing the IssuerSigningKey during runtime?**

Ideas that come to mind:

- keep a reference to TokenValidationParameters and just replace the IssuerSigningKey
- extend SymmetricSecurityKey and do something similar as in the previous point

Both of these ways seem too hacky. I assume there is some kind of mechanism to achieve this the right way, I just couldn't find it.

Answer (score 11):

I know this an old thread, but posting my answer anyway because I stumbled upon this thread while searching for the same scenario and I think it might be useful for others.

There is a delegate `IssuerSigningKeyResolver`, in the TokenValidationParameters, that you can set while configuring the other options. On every request authentication, your delegate will be executed. You can dynamically return the the `SecurityKey`.

For example:

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuer = false,
                ValidateAudience = false,
                ValidateLifetime = true,
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,

                //ValidIssuer = jwtSettings.ValidIssuer,
                //ValidAudience = jwtSettings.ValidAudience,
                //IssuerSigningKey = issuerSigningKey,
                IssuerSigningKeyResolver = (token, secutiryToken, kid, validationParameters) =>
                {
                    SecurityKey issuerSigningKey = null;
                    // Set issuerSigningKey as per your logic.
                    // This delegate will be executed for eahc request.

                    return new List<SecurityKey>() { issuerSigningKey };
                }

            };

        });
```

Comment: Thank you, this is a good answer, but unfortunately this delegate requires concrete code and cannot use a service to obtain the secret key, for example using Azure Key Vault via an injected service. We could code the key retrieval here, but that would break the whole point of DI.

Comment: Toad, you are wrong about breaking the DI here. We are in the "Startup.cs" here. From a DI point of view, the "Startup.cs" is what is called the "composition root" in DI speak. So this is the one place in the application where you can (and often must) reference things directly. (E.g. to register them for the rest of the application.)