# Can authentication IssuerSigningKeys be updated at runtime?

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, .net-5

On startup I have the following

```
var keys = GetKeys();

services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            RequireExpirationTime = true,
            ValidateIssuer = false,
            ValidateAudience = false,
            IssuerSigningKeys = keys
        };
    });
```

The list of valid keys can change at runtime - is it possible to update the list that the authentication layer is using without having to restart the server?

The idea is that we have multiple client servers calling our API and they all have their own keys they use for signing the JWT.
New clients can be added at any time (via another API).
This is a requirement that I've received from above and it's unlikely I can get the design changed.

Comment: @Chaodeng - that is exactly what I wanted; don't know why it didn't show up when I searched the site. If you want to put that into an answer, I accept it to give you more rep.

Answer (score 1):

There is a delegate IssuerSigningKeyResolver, in the TokenValidationParameters, that you can set while configuring the other options. On every request authentication, your delegate will be executed. You can dynamically return the the SecurityKey.This post can refer to：[ASP.NET Core - change JWT SecurityKey during runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54167610/asp-net-core-change-jwt-securitykey-during-runtime)